# extra input box phonegap jquerymobile

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile, iscrollview

I'm using scroller form [iscrollview](https://github.com/watusi/jquery-mobile-iscrollview). It's truly appreciated.
I am using a JQM 1.3 . The form has some input field. However, when I type a character, and scrolls it overlays an extra input box . This didn't happen until I implemented iscrollview. Any help would be appreciated.
thanks.

Answer (score 2):

use

```
-webkit-user-modify: read-write-plaintext-only;
```

Comment: use it but problem with <input type="number"> on android numpad

Comment: this will show alphabetical keyboard instead of numpad when used on number inputs.

Comment: but needed number for <input type="number">

Answer (score 1):

I did workaround by loosing focus of current input when user scrolls.

I've created empty input with position:absolute, and left: -400em (so it won't be visible) and added listener for scroll event:

JS:

```
$(document).delegate("#main-page", "iscroll_onscrollmove", function () {
  if($("#some-input).is(":focus")){
    //$("#some-input).blur() //in order to hide virtual keyboard uncomment 
    $("#focus-target").focus();
  }
});
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="focus-target" style="width: 0; height: 0; position: absolute; left: -400em;"/>
```

So far I've tested only on Android. It doesn't solve the root problem, but scrolling input is no longer visible for a user.